# Usar JavaScript com AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

Tenho um formulário em uma pagina JSP.
Quando o cliente digitar o CPF, via AJAX, pego o CPF faço uma consulta no banco, caso ela ja tenha se cadastrado. Pego todos os dados dele, e preencho os campos automaticamente.

Só que estou com problema, o AJAX chama a pagina carrega_cpf.jsp

Porem quando coloco o JavaScript nessa pagina, para ele popular os campos do formulário, não funciona.

Alguém sabe alguma alternativa, para fazer o JavaScript funcionar na pagina que é carregada pelo AJAX ?

Comment: Mas se vc já tem um formulário que preenche os campos automaticamente, qual é o problema que está ocorrendo? Para que colocar outro Javascript na página? Não entendi, ficou confusa sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma página recebe o **cpf** como parâmetro e retorna os dados do cliente em [json](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Fazendo isso, você realiza a busca com o `ajax`, e preenche os valores no `inputs`.
Vou deixar um exemplo utilizando CEP's como base.

Primeiro você cria o seu form:

```
   <div class="well">
    <form class="form row" action="checkout-sample" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
            <label>CEP</label><input id="cep" class="form-control" name="cep" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
            <label>Estado</label><input id="estado" class="form-control" name="estado" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label>Cidade</label><input id="cidade" class="form-control" name="cidade" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
            <label>Bairro</label><input id="bairro" class="form-control" name="bairro" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label>Endereço</label><input id="endereco" class="form-control" name="endereco" type="text">
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Neste exemplo, o usuário irá digitar o CEP, e após ele sair do `input`, será chamada a função para buscar os dados.

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("input#cep").change(function(){
      var cep_code = $(this).val();
      if( cep_code.length <= 0 ) return;
      alert("Enviando consulta do CEP "+cep_code);
      $.get("http://apps.widenet.com.br/busca-cep/api/cep.json", { code: cep_code },
         function(result){
            if( result.status!=1 ){
               alert(result.message || "Houve um erro desconhecido");
               return;
            }
            $("input#cep").val( result.code );
            $("input#estado").val( result.state );
            $("input#cidade").val( result.city );
            $("input#bairro").val( result.district );
            $("input#endereco").val( result.address );
            $("input#estado").val( result.state );
            //alert("Dados recebidos e alterados");
         });
   });
});
```

Não tenho informações de como está seu código [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp), mas se tiver alguma dúvida em como retornar os dados em [json](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), olhe [este link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/creating-parsing-json-data-with-java-servlet-struts-jsp-json/).

```js
jQuery(function($){
   $("input#cep").change(function(){
      var cep_code = $(this).val();
      if( cep_code.length <= 0 ) return;
      alert("Enviando consulta do CEP "+cep_code);
      $.get("http://apps.widenet.com.br/busca-cep/api/cep.json", { code: cep_code },
         function(result){
            if( result.status!=1 ){
               alert(result.message || "Houve um erro desconhecido");
               return;
            }
            $("input#cep").val( result.code );
            $("input#estado").val( result.state );
            $("input#cidade").val( result.city );
            $("input#bairro").val( result.district );
            $("input#endereco").val( result.address );
            $("input#estado").val( result.state );
            //alert("Dados recebidos e alterados");
         });
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well"><form class="form row" action="checkout-sample" method="POST">
<div class="form-group col-sm-2"><label>CEP</label><input id="cep" class="form-control" name="cep" type="text"></div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-2"><label>Estado</label><input id="estado" class="form-control" name="estado" type="text"></div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-3"><label>Cidade</label><input id="cidade" class="form-control" name="cidade" type="text"></div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-2"><label>Bairro</label><input id="bairro" class="form-control" name="bairro" type="text"></div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-3"><label>Endereço</label><input id="endereco" class="form-control" name="endereco" type="text"></div>
</form>

</div>
```

Se preferir, aqui tem um [exemplo no JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/randrade/9m6unx63/1/embedded/result/).

Créditos do exemplo: [Busca CEP](http://apps.widenet.com.br/busca-cep)